# notepad ++ - need help docking windows

Tags: notepad++

My NppFTP window used to be docked on the right, like this:

[image]

But, I clicked something accidentally, and now, it's detached as a separate window:

[image]

I can manually resize the window, and move it around. I can also dock it horizontally at the top by double-clicking the title. But I can't figure out how to re-dock it on the right.

Comment: This should really be asked over on https://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with that site. I'll post this question over there.

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on the top of the window.

or move it to the right border of the main window.

Comment: Double clicking docks it horizontally at the top, not vertically on the right